# C++ Assignment Hook for User Defined Datatype

Tags: c++, variable-assignment

## Problem

Cache previous variable entries into an array, when that original variable is updated. Essentially, attempting to develop an **assignment hook** for the `(int)` `COORDINATE.x` & `(int)` `COORDINATE.y` variables; shown below.

## Code

### Coordinate

```cpp
struct COORDINATE
{
    int x, y;
    
    COORDINATE ( int x, int y )
    {
        this->x = x;
        this->y = y;
    }

    COORDINATE ( ) { };

    ~COORDINATE ( ) { };
};
```

### Entity

```cpp
struct ENTITY
{
    COORDINATE location;

    COORDINATE location_cache[10];
    
    ENTITY ( COORDINATE location )
    {
        this->location = location;
    }

    ENTITY ( ) { };

    ~ENTITY ( ) { };
};
```

### Main

```cpp
int main ( )
{
    Entity entity[50];

    for ( int i = 0; i < 50; i++ )
    {
        entity[i].location.x = new_generated_value;   // <- Store previous value in location_cache[0]
        entity[i].location.y = new_generated_value;   // <- Store previous value in location_cache[0]
    }

    return 0;
}
```

## Goal

When either...

- `ENTITY->location`
- `ENTITY->location.x`
- `ENTITY->location.y`

... is updated (with any new value), update

- `ENTITY->location_cache[n]`

  or
- `ENTITY->location_cache[n].x`  &&  `ENTITY->location_cache[n].y`

... automatically.

## Thoughts

This can obviously be easily handled by invoking user-defined setter, however, I'm attempting to identify whether this 'store' procedure can be invoked via another method.

Comment: You'd have to refactor your program a bit to accomplish this. In particular, you can't use an assignment operator on an `int` to do what you want.

Comment: I think there's probably a better way to do whatever you're trying to solve though.

Comment: There is nothing like an "assignment hook" in C++. You can only replace the type of `x` and `y` with a custom one that overloads the assignment operator with whatever behavior you want. Keeping them just normal `int`s makes it impossible. Whether wrapping the `int`s in such custom classes is feasible depends on whether other functions using them are fine with such a type change. With a `operator int` you can get automatic conversion to `int` where needed, but in particular passing `int&` reference or `int*` pointers will be impossible while keeping the modified semantics.

Comment: Replace `int x, y;` with `CachedInt x, y;` that have custom assignment operators and `operator int()`. That way you need to custom getter/setter.